# How to write sql query to select rows having which does not contain any of the values in array

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  code
1   a
1   b
1   c
1   d
1   e
2   a
2   b
2   d
2   e
3   a
3   d
3   e
```

this is my table here (2,c) and (3,b) is missing out , so how to get only the missing out Id's keeping the code values (a,b,c,d,e,f) as static values even if any of the combination of ID and Code is missing.
Eg:(1,a),(1,b),(1,c),(1,d),(1,e) are mandatory i need the ID as 1 even if (1,c) is missing out

Comment: @RiggsFolly using NOT IN considering only code column is not giving the correct result , even if any one of code value in (a,b,c,d,e) is missing i need that id

Comment: Is there duplicate entry possible? Like twice 1 a.

Comment: yes it can be there

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select i.id, c.code
from (select distinct id from t) i cross join
     (select distinct code from t) c left join
     t
     on t.id = i.id and t.code = c.code
where t.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,code CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'a'),
(1,'b'),
(1,'c'),
(1,'d'),
(1,'e'),
(2,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(2,'d'),
(2,'e'),
(3,'a'),
(3,'d'),
(3,'e');

SELECT DISTINCT x.id
              , y.code 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
           LEFT 
           JOIN my_table z 
             ON z.id = x.id 
            AND z.code = y.code 
          WHERE z.id IS NULL;
+----+------+
| id | code |
+----+------+
|  3 | b    |
|  2 | c    |
|  3 | c    |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Hi thank for the support but this is giving a syntax error

Comment: Plainly, that's not true.